# What is the meaning of this content property in CSS?

Tags: css

```
content: "."
```

I am especially curious about the meaning of the point in the middle of the two quotes.

Comment: It's a period. It means to put a period in the content of an element that supports the content property.  http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QpQVYz

Comment: Content is a pseudo selector that you can use in order to focus on specific "content" that you are looking to adjust. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)?

Comment: @MikeDiglio No, `content` is not a "pseudo-selector", or any kind of selector at all. It's a **property**, used with the pseudo-**elements** `::before` and `::after`. It's not used to "focus" on anything; it's used to place that content in the before or after pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

go through the link,

https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

you will get an idea about content.